# Ideals in $3$-dimensional algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $A$ be the $3$-dimensional algebra over $\mathbb C$ with basis $1,x,x^2$ and $x^3=1$. Let $B$ be the $3$-dimensional commutative algebra over $\mathbb C$ with basis $1,x,y$ and $x^2=xy=y^2=0$. Show that $A$ has only finitely many ideals, but $B$ has infinitely many.

---

My attempt:

After some calculation, I find that we only have trivial ideals $(0)$ and $(1)$ in $A$. But I don't know why $B$ has infinitely many ideals. I can only find ideals $ (0),(x),(y),(x,y),(1) $ in $B$. What am I missing?

Comment: Is the ideal $(x+y)$  contained in your list?

Comment: @MMM You are right! Probably I am missing ideals $(x+ay)$ for all $a\in\mathbb C$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per, MMM's comment: the non-zero elements of $ax + by + c$. If $c \ne 0$ then this is invertible:

$$ (ax + by + c)(ax - c)(by - c) = c^3. $$

So the non-zero, non-invertible elements look like $ax + by$ for various $a$ and $b$.

To see that, for instance $(x + y) \ne (x - y)$, observe that for instance

$$ (x + y)(ax + by + c) = c(x + y).$$

Comment: @Bach I misread it as $x^3 = 0$, that's on me.

Comment: But then we should still be able to factor $x^3 - 1 = (x - 1)(x + \omega)(x - \omega)$ and get ideals $(x - 1), (x \pm \omega)$. @Bach

Comment: In $\mathbb{C}[x]$, not in $\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^3 - 1)$.

Comment: Yeah, I am also missing these three ideals. Thank you!